# How to append a string to a file from the nth line onwards in shell script?

Tags: shell, sed, sh

I want to add a string to the file at the end of each line starting from the second line .

so this is my file budget.txt

```
id,budget
d4385ff7-247f-407a-97c6-366d8128c6c7,
50548d0a-257c-44f5-b175-2e7efa53dc35,
e15965cf-ffc1-40ae-94c4-b450ab190233,
b9286b97-2575-4c98-bd24-1393d5309e76,
```

the output i am expecting is below. I want to add the string 'True' starting from the second line onwards in the end.

```
id,budget
d4385ff7-247f-407a-97c6-366d8128c6c7,True
50548d0a-257c-44f5-b175-2e7efa53dc35,True
e15965cf-ffc1-40ae-94c4-b450ab190233,True
b9286b97-2575-4c98-bd24-1393d5309e76,True
```

what could be the shortest bash command .
thank you so much
appreciate any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure to run `dos2unix budget.txt` on your file before running the commands below, in general `.txt` files are originated on windows so have different line ending.

```
awk 'NR>1{$0=$0"True"}1' file
id,budget
d4385ff7-247f-407a-97c6-366d8128c6c7,True
50548d0a-257c-44f5-b175-2e7efa53dc35,True
e15965cf-ffc1-40ae-94c4-b450ab190233,True
b9286b97-2575-4c98-bd24-1393d5309e76,True
```

Here, `NR` is the number of record and by the default nature of `awk` record is same as line. So if you do `NR>1` it will tell `awk` to perform action inside `{..}` on the lines number greater than 1.

Or use `sed`, here replace end of line `$` with `True`:

```
sed '2,$s/$/True/' file
id,budget
d4385ff7-247f-407a-97c6-366d8128c6c7,True
50548d0a-257c-44f5-b175-2e7efa53dc35,True
e15965cf-ffc1-40ae-94c4-b450ab190233,True
b9286b97-2575-4c98-bd24-1393d5309e76,True
```

Comment: this added to the beginning of the line

Comment: Rather than `sed -e '2,$...`, it is probably cleaner to write `sed -e '1!s/$/True/'` Purely stylistic choice.

Comment: Also, using the context (the trailing comma): `sed -e 's/,$/,True/'`